# Не выводится переменная

Tags: python, рекурсия

Почему у меня тут не выводится переменная number? Не могу понять

```
def rec():
    number = int(input())
    if number == 0:
        return
    return rec()
    print(number)
rec()
```

Хотя в таком исполнении она выводится:

```
def reverse():
    number = int(input())
    if number != 0:
        reverse()
    print(number)
reverse()
```

Comment: Потому что у Вас вывод после return и функция на принт уже не попадает.

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `return` завершает текущее выполнение функции и производит *возвра* значения в точку вызова, соответственно, `print` и что угодно ещё после ретёрна не работает. Варианта решения есть разные.

Либо печатайте перед возвратом значения:

```py
def rec():
    number = int(input())
    if number == 0:
        return
    print(number)
    return rec()

rec()
```

Либо, что лучше, печатайте результат выполнения функции:

```py
def rec():
    number = int(input())
    if number == 0:
        return
    return rec()

print(rec())
```

Лучший это вариант потому, что функции должны делать что-то одно конкретное, в данном случае это запрос на ввод числа, а отображение этого числа уже отдельная задача.

Кстати, задачу проще решить без рекурсии:

```py
def rec():
    number = 0
    while number == 0:
        number = int(input())
    return number

print(rec())
```

Answer (score -1):

После оператора `return` функция прекращает работу, как `break;`, но только возвращает информацию.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // кажется, это всего лишь ответный комментарий на чужой ответ/комментарий. значит, стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Это уже сказал @AivanF.